# Azure Devops Reporting or Queries To Determine Which PBIs have open Github PRs

Tags: azure-devops

The problem I am facing is some Product Backlog Items (PBIs) are marked as done, but in some instances the Pull Request (PR) on the PBI was never merged.

We do have Github integrated with our pipeline and the PBIs so we can see the current state of the PR on the PBI.

I would like the ability to create a query or run some type of report that helps me audit the state of all PBIs in Azure Devops and any that are marked with a specific state (Done in this case) that has a PR that still has a status of Open instead of Merged.

Answer (score 0):

Azure Boards doesn't yet have the capability to use GitHub links as query parameters.  That said, it is on the backlog to enable scenarios such as this one.

It would be helpful if you created a feature suggestion for this on the [Azure DevOps Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/21/index.html).  Doing so will allow us to link the suggestion to our backlog item, which will give updates when work is started/completed on that feature.